# Backbone save with no sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, persistence

I have a scenario where i'd like to send an update to the server, but I don't want the response b/c it's a costly operation. I tried to patch the url to have an extra query string param like "nothing=true", but I'm struggling to get that work reliably.

```
@save({columns: columns})
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the model's `save` operation, adding the custom flag:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // customizations...

    // override save
    save: function(key, value, options) {
      if (options.ignoreResponse) { // conditionally ignore the server response
          options = _.extend(options || {}, {
              attrs: _.extend(myModel.toJSON(), {
                  // Add custom property
                  'respondWith': 'nothing'
              })
          });
      }
      return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.apply(this, [key, value, options]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but the model persists longer than that change, and at times, the save would need to be the standard save method. I ended up changing url to add the nothing=true to the end and then changing it back after the save operation in the method. It seems a little ghetto, but I haven't found anything else more elegant.

Comment: I think any solution to this problem is going to be a little ghetto. :) I modded the above code to facilitate conditionally ignoring the server response.